# Does Jquery work well in quirks mode?

Tags: jquery, doctype

For reasons beyond my control, the site works in quirks mode. Will Jquery help me in this situation?

I expect the jquery developers concentrate on strict mode today - the mode of the future. On the other hand, all those libraries once started to ease the pain of working in quirks mode.

Comment: "Transitional" HTML/XHTML and quirks rendering modes in browsers are two different topics.  You may want to consider editing the title of this question.

Answer (score 5):

NO!

According to [official jQuery site v. 1.8.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/):

> Don’t use Quirks mode! **jQuery has never supported Quirks mode and we
>   do not perform any testing in Quirks**. This can affect values like
>   `$("window").height()`, and the jQuery 1.8 Quirks mode results did
>   change in order to support some modern browser features. The majority
>   of problem cases we’ve seen are from developers that wanted to be in
>   Standards mode but had an invalid doctype or extraneous markup before
>   their  tag. When in doubt, use the simple and short `<!doctype html>`.

Answer (score 4):

By some accounts, it works in quirks mode but the performance is horrible, see:

- http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/johnteague/archive/2009/09/14/jquery-does-not-like-quirksmode.aspx
- http://blog.yourinnovative.com/the-development-lab/jquery-quirks-mode-in-ie6/

Answer (score 2):

According to [jQuery Migrate Plugin - Warning Messages](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md)

> JQMIGRATE: jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode
>
> Cause: A browser runs in "quirks mode" when the HTML document does not have a `<!doctype ...>` as its first non-blank line, or when the doctype in the file is invalid. This mode causes the browser to emulate 1990s-era (HTML3) behavior. In Internet Explorer, it also causes many high-performance APIs to be hidden in order to better emulate ancient browsers. jQuery has never been compatible with, or tested in, quirks mode.
>
> Solution: Put a valid doctype in the document and ensure that the document is rendering in standards mode. The simplest valid doctype is the HTML5 one, which we highly recommend: `<!doctype html>` . The jQuery Migrate plugin does not attempt to fix issues related to quirks mode.