# If DOCTYPE is not specified on Chrome, Firefox, or Safari, is there a way to find the viewport's height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, doctype, quirks-mode

The following code can correctly find the viewport's height, either using plain JavaScript or jQuery, but what if the `DOCTYPE` is not specified, then both lines that reported something like `410` would now report something like `3016`.

Is there a way to find the viewport's height if `DOCTYPE` is not specified?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
    body { height: 3000px; }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    onload = function() {
        console.log("jQuery version", $.fn.jquery);
        console.log("document.compatMode is", document.compatMode);

        // using jQuery
        console.log("$(window).height() is", $(window).height());

        // using plain JavaScript
        console.log("document.documentElement.clientHeight is", document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    hi
```

Comment: jQuery does not support Quirks mode BTW.

Comment: And `height: 3000;` is not valid in non-quirks mode. Did you mean `3000px`?

Comment: careless mistake. corrected now

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic JS which should work in most browsers (FF, Cr, IE6+):

```
var viewportHeight;
var viewportWidth;
if (document.compatMode === 'BackCompat') {
    viewportHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    viewportWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
} else {
    viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}
```

Reference :
[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To get viewport height:

```
console.log(window.innerHeight);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/UWijAdI/1/edit)

- *[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.innerHeight)*

Tested in quirky Chrome and Firefox.

---

Side note: [jQuery does not support quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284854/1331430). Using jQuery on a quirky page (no doctype specificied) may have an unexpected outcome. It is not tested in quirks mode and if it ever breaks, you won't get any support.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue while developing a bookmarklet where I could not control whether or not the DOCTYPE was present. Eventually, I found [this](http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript) post that made my life so much easier!

Here is a simple **javascript only** function to determine the viewport/window sizing:

```
function viewport(){
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if(!('innerWidth' in window)){
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width  : e[a+'Width'], height : e[a+'Height'] };
}
```

Usage:

```
var vp = viewport(),
    h = vp.height,
    w = vp.width;
```

or

```
var h = viewport().height,
    w = viewport().width;
```

We can all thank Andy Langston, whoever he is (;